# Using SQL to find customers who ordered first time in July

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with column names :

```
order_id (bigint), 
user_id(bigint) , 
team_leader (text), 
processing_at (date).
```

I want to find Number of customers who ordered in `July` for the first time,
i.e. they did not place an order before `July`.
I am learning `MySQL`. Can anyone help me with this question?

Table got 73159 rows.

Comment: How would anyone find the number of customers if you did not specify any info on customers.

Comment: number of customer i think question means to point toward user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE processing_at >= '2021-07-01' AND processing_at < '2021-08-01' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND
                        t2.processing_at < '2021-07-01');
```

The above query counts the number of distinct users who placed any order in the month of July, 2021.  The condition that this July order be the first order is enforced by exists logic, which asserts that we cannot find any order for that user in a month earlier than July.

**Edit:**

Regarding performance, the above query might benefit from the following compound index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (processing_at, user_id);
```

This index, if used, would cover both `WHERE` clauses, as well as the outer `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Hi, Tried it but its taking too long to finish the query. Any suggestions from your side? Forgot to tell you that table has 73159 rows.

Comment: @Hitesh Check the updated answer for an index option which might help performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also approach this using two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select user_id, min(processing_at) as first_processing_at
      from orders
      where processing_at < '2021-08-01'
      group by user_id
      having min(processing_at) >= '2021-07-01'
     ) u;
```

Given that you are using MySQL, I'm not sure if this will be faster than a `not exists` approach, but it is worth trying.